# Estoy intentando enviar una solicitud POST de Ajax usando Jquery, pero tengo un error de solicitud incorrecta 400

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Aquí esta mi código de Ajax, me saca estos errores:

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:5137/Compras/Create 400 (Bad
> Request) send@jquery.min.js:2 ajax@jquery.min.js:2
> enviarDatos@Create:266 (anónimo)@Create:199 Create:275
> error@Create:275 c@jquery.min.js:2 fireWith@jquery.min.js:2
> l@jquery.min.js:2 (anónimo)@jquery.min.js:2 load (asincrónica)
> send@jquery.min.js:2 ajax@jquery.min.js:2 enviarDatos@Create:266
> (anónimo)